# Determining if there is a solution to $2004x^2+2005y=1$ for integers $x,y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an equation and need to decide if there is a solution to
$$2004x^2+2005y=1,$$ 
where $x$ and $y$ are integers. A clue: $2005=5\cdot401$ and $401$ is a prime number.

How to start question like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work modulo $2005$.

You will get $$x^2 \equiv -1 (\bmod 2005) \Leftrightarrow x^2 \equiv -1 (\bmod 5),\; x^2 \equiv -1 (\bmod 401).$$

To see that this is solvable you can use quadratic reciprocity: it's enough that $5,\; 401 \equiv 1 (\bmod 4).$

Since such an $x$ satisfies $2004x^2 \equiv 1 (\bmod 2005)$, there is an integer $y$ such that $$2004x^2 + 2005 = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \  x^2\equiv-1\ \ (mod\ 5\cdot 401)\!\iff\! \bigg\lbrace\begin{eqnarray}\rm x^2\equiv -1&\equiv& 4 &&\rm (mod\ 5) \\ \rm x^2\equiv -1&\equiv& 400 &&\rm (mod\ 401)\end{eqnarray}\!\bigg\rbrace,\: $ and $\rm\ 4,\,400\ $ are squares.